# valgrind error m_execontext.c:411 (record_ExeContext_wrk2) on jetson nano

Tags: ubuntu, valgrind, nvidia-jetson

I am trying to trace memory consumption on my nvidia jetson nano with valgrind but I get:

```
stiv@nano:~/jsoft/dgpu_core$ valgrind --tool=massif ./build/dgpu_core
==8379== Massif, a heap profiler
==8379== Copyright (C) 2003-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Nicholas Nethercote
==8379== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8379== Command: ./build/dgpu_core
==8379==

valgrind: m_execontext.c:411 (record_ExeContext_wrk2): Assertion 'n_ips >= 1 && n_ips <= VG_(clo_backtrace_size)' failed.

host stacktrace:
==8379==    at 0x5800A0A8: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/massif-arm64-linux)

sched status:
  running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable (lwpid 8379)
==8379==    at 0x4842E9C: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_massif-arm64-linux.so)


Note: see also the FAQ in the source distribution.
It contains workarounds to several common problems.
In particular, if Valgrind aborted or crashed after
identifying problems in your program, there's a good chance
that fixing those problems will prevent Valgrind aborting or
crashing, especially if it happened in m_mallocfree.c.

If that doesn't help, please report this bug to: www.valgrind.org

In the bug report, send all the above text, the valgrind
version, and what OS and version you are using.  Thanks.
```

What does it mean?
Is there some known way how to walkaround this problem?

Comment: Can you try with Valgrind 3.16? Does your app run clean under memcheck? Your problem is that Valgrind is seeing a stack depth that is outside of the range that it is expecting.

Comment: @PaulFloyd This helped, please post this advice as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that Valgrind is seeing a stack depth that is outside of the range that it is expecting.

My recommendations are

1. Always make sure that your application runs clean with memcheck before using other Valgrind tools.
2. Use the latest version of Valgrind (currently 3.16.1 at the time of writing, July 2020).